# Я не могу решить ошибку при импорте библиотеки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Короче суть такова: когда я импортирую модуль gtts:

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

у меня возникает ошибка:

```
AttributeError: module 'soupsieve.css_types' has no attribute 'SEL_DIR_LTR'
```

До этого у меня всё нормально работало. Я думаю, что ошибка возникает из-за того, что я обновил питон до версии 3.8.1, хотя даже после обновления я запускал свою программу и всё работало.

Можете подсказать как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: gtts поддерживает Python 3.8, в ошибке сказано, что в модуле нет 'soupsieve.css_types' нет атрибута 'SEL_DIR_LTR'... а у вас последняя версия модуля стоит?

Comment: Да, у меня последняя версия модуля, я даже его удалял и снова устанавливал

Comment: я бы порекомендовал уйти на стабильную версию 3.7.4

Comment: Первое, проблема связана не с gTTS модулем, а с [soupsieve](https://pypi.org/project/soupsieve/), покажите полный текст ошибки, потому что в исходниках такой аттрибут есть.